# objective-c parsing of objects that contain objects of the same type within

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing

i want to parse an xml like:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <userName>mspeller</userName>
    <firstName>Mike</firstName>
    <lastName>Speller</lastName>
    <user>
      <userName>mspeller</userName>
      <firstName>Mike</firstName>
      <lastName>Speller</lastName>
    </user>
    <user>
      <userName>mspeller</userName>
      <firstName>Mike</firstName>
      <lastName>Speller</lastName>
    </user>
    ...
  </user>
  <user>
    <userName>mgdan</userName>
    <firstName>Mila</firstName>
    <lastName>Gdan</lastName>
  </user>
  ...
</users>
```

us you see, this xml contain objects //user that contain other users, please help !

Comment: I think he is having trouble parsing because multiple user is nested and wants to know how to keep track of the state of the parser...but yea, it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class:

```
@interface User : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic,retain)User *secondaryUser;
```

whenever startElement is userName simply initialize the secondary user under User and set attributes that u want.
It worked fine for me .hope this should help u.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be difficult to parse this. Just keep a BOOL flag and set it to YES when you are two levels deep. When you hit 'didEndElement' callback, if it's set to YES, it means you are two levels deep and unset it to NO. Otherwise it means you are in first level.

If there's arbitrary levels of nested users, then simply have an int that will indicate the nth level of user...each time you hit 'didStartElement', increment it. In 'didEndElement', decrement it. Also, you will probably need a stack type data structure...

****EDIT:****This is assuming you are using event-driven parser like NSXMLParser...

Comment: OK i see, but please do you have any tutorial with NSXMLParser, xmlDigester or other that parse xml like that ..

Comment: Apple has a pretty nice guide on parsing using NSXMLParser. Search 'NSXMLParser' on google, it's the 2nd result.

Comment: I realy meen it, i didn't find any thing on the net about nested object parsing, pleeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaase help!